# Submit data with jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have couple of inputs i'd like to submit just like i would with a form and set an action to it.

Is it possible through jquery ?

Here is my js :

```
$(".flex-login-submit").click(submitForm);
function submitForm() {
    if (!$('[name="id"]').val().length || !$('[name="password"]').val().length) {
        console.log("Too small");
        $('.errors').empty();
        $('.errors').append('<div class="animated fadeOut">Veillez à remplir tous les champs.</div>');

    } else {
        $('.flex-login-container').attrib('action', 'submitForm');
        $('.flex-login-container').submit();
    }
}
```

And my jsp :

```
<div class="flex-login-container">
    <div class="flex-login-title">Veuillez  vous authentifier</div>
    <input class="flex-login-infos" name="id" placeholder="Identifiant">
    <input class="flex-login-infos" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe">
    <div class="flex-login-submit">Se connecter</div>
    <div class="flex-login-help">Mot de passe oublié?</div>
    <div class="errors"><br/></div>
</div>
```

I'm gettin an error message "attr" is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct function name is attr. You are using attrib in your code.

You are adding a action attribute to a div. If you want to use submit you will have to use a form element instead.

Alternatively you could use an ajax function to submit your form on click.

```
      $(".flex-login-submit").click(submitForm);
function submitForm() {
    if (!$('[name="id"]').val().length || !$('[name="password"]').val().length) {
        console.log("Too small");
        $('.errors').empty();
        $('.errors').append('<div class="animated fadeOut">Veillez à remplir tous les champs.</div>');

    } else {

              //ajax function here
              $.ajax({

                   url:"put your url here",
                   data: put your data here,
                   success:function(data){

                     //do something with data here

                   }


              });


    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @LarryLane - However the submit does'nt submit anything nor redirect me anywhere. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

I could be totally wrong, but I thought you need to have a form to submit a form.  Try this...

**HTML**

```
<form id="flex-login-form" action="ACTION_URL_HERE" method="post">
<div class="flex-login-container">
    <div class="flex-login-title">Veuillez  vous authentifier</div>
    <input class="flex-login-infos" name="id" placeholder="Identifiant">
    <input class="flex-login-infos" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe">
    <div class="flex-login-submit">Se connecter</div>
    <div class="flex-login-help">Mot de passe oublié?</div>
    <div class="errors"><br/></div>
</div>
</form>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(".flex-login-submit").on('click', function() {
    if (!$('[name="id"]').val().length || !$('[name="password"]').val().length) {
        console.log("Too small");
        $('.errors').empty();
        $('.errors').append('<div class="animated fadeOut">Veillez à remplir tous les champs.</div>');
    } else {
        $('#flex-login-form').submit();
    }
});
```